# Control height of multiple images by its parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I've got 2 divs lined side by side. Now I'm calling 2 external images (120px X 50px) into a div. How do I scale both images by giving a height: percentage value to `bannerStrip`? So basically I want to control the height of the 2 images by its wrapper (while maintaining the images aspect-raito).

html:

```
<div class="row" id="bannerStrip">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8"><img class="bannerBarInner" src="advert.png"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><img class="bannerBarInner" src="logo.png"></div>
    </div>
```

css (what I tried. not successful though):

```
#bannerStrip{
  height: 75%;
  width: auto;
}
.bannerBarInner{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use img-responsive bootstrap class.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="advert.png">
```